# how to list installed applications in windows 8 metroui

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I am just curious if there is a way to find installed metro applications within an application. I mean, I like to create an app which also shows my other apps and I want to show them as "Get it from store" or "Launch". Thank you...

Comment: I've tried PackageManager, but received unauthorizedaccessexception. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.management.deployment.packagemanager

Comment: PackageManager is for desktop apps only.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible.  Windows Store apps are heavily sandboxed, and this is one of the things that is disallowed.

Comment: could you provide some MSDN link for this?